# How to stop waiting the Webdriver until page load completes, As the page is taking ~ 3 minutes to complete in VPN connection?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

How to stop waiting the Webdriver until page load completes, As the page is taking ~ 3 minutes to complete in VPN connection, though the page is actually loaded. Few resources taking ~3 minutes time load in VPN environment.

I tried to skip loading those resources using selenium proxy but did not succeeded.

Comment: @DebanjanB This is a bad dup target. OP is asking how NOT to wait until the page is done loading... NOT how to wait until the page is done loading.